# Matlab loop over variables (beginner)

Tags: matlab

I would like to apply a function to several variables. Is there a nice way to do this?

Like:

```
M = ones(2,2)
N = zeros(3,3)
M = M + 1
N = N + 1
```

Works but I would like do something of the sort:

```
M = ones(2,2)
N = zeros(3,3)
L = ?UnknownStructure?(M, N)
for i = 1:length(L)
    L(i) = L(i) + 1
end
```

Or is there a better way entirely to apply a function to a set of variables?

Comment: I guess you could use `evalin`, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use cells:

```
M = ones(2,2)
N = zeros(3,3)
L = {M, N};
funct=@(x) x+1;
L2=cellfun(funct, L, 'UniformOutput',false);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as references in Matlab, in a sense that you can have two different variable names pointing to the same matrix.

However, you can have an array of matrices.

```
L = { M, N };
for i = 1:length(L)
    L{i} = L{i} + 1
end
```

I tested this code in Octave. However note: The source matrices M, N are unchanged by this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
a = ones(2,2)
arrayfun(@(x) 2*x , a)
```

You can make the function (`2*x`) whatever you want.

Comment: I still don't see how to apply this function to several such matrices.